# How to remove icons of system utilities from launchpad in macOS?

Tags: macos

I know most where most, if not all, system utilities are located in macOS and I don't need them to be seen in the launchpad as default. So how can I remove these icons from the launchpad?

Comment: To my knowledge Launchpad only shows items in the Applications folder.  What sytem utilities are you referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it is generally not possible to remove Apple installed apps from launchpad without jumping through a number of hoops. Some of these hoops can be found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144756/how-to-remove-an-icon-from-launchpad-that-does-not-appear-in-the-finder

However it might be better and/or easier to put all the apps you don't want in a single "folder" together on launchpad.

Just drag one on top of the other to create the folder (Just like on iOS) name it what you want ("misc," etc.) and put everything you are sick of looking at in that one folder and stick it at the end of the screens. That's how I do it.